# Calculating number of edges between tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples

Trying to calculate the number of edges between the tuples in case if I have tuple `a` and `b`

For example, if `a = ((0,1),(0,2),(0,3))` and `b = (((0),(1,2,3)), ((0,1),(2,3)), ((0,1,2),(3)))`

Desirable output is `[3,2,1]` because a - representing all edges that we have and b - all the possible cuts of graph that we have.

Came to the solution that calculates the overall amount of such edges (in our example - 6):

```
def cnt_edges(a,b):
   edge_cnt = 0
   
   for i in range(len(a)):
       node1 = a[i][0]
       node2 = a[i][1]
       
       for j in range(len(b)):
           inner_node1 = b[j][0]
           inner_node2 = b[j][1]
           
           if (node1 in inner_node1 and node2 in inner_node2) or (node1 in inner_node2 and node2 in inner_node1):
               edge_cnt += 1
   return edge_cnt

a = ((0, 1),(0, 2), (0,3))
b = (((0),(1,2,3)), ((0,1),(2,3)), ((0,1,2),(3)))

cnt_edges(a,b)
```

How can I calucalate it for each particular tuple in b?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `a` contains the list of edges : `0 to 1`, `0 to 2` and `0 to 3`, which means that the node `0` is connected to the three other nodes ? And each they are only connected to `0` ? And `b` is a list of partitions of these 4 nodes ? And you want to count the edges between the 2 partitions ?

Comment: for example, a = ((0,1),(1,2)) - means that we have three nodes 0,1,2 and two edges - 0,1 and 1,2 (basically, we receive triangle-graph in this example). then b = ((0,),(1,2),(0,1),(2)) - it means that we took all our nodes sorted (0,1,2) and did several "cuts" adding one node until len(b) - 0 and 1,2 then 0,1 and 2. If we would have node 3 - then b will look like 0 and 1,2,3, 0,1 and 2,3, 0,1,2 and 3.

Comment: Let's say we have a = ((0,1),(1,2)) and b = ((0,),(1,2),(0,1),(2)). What I try to receive is the list(or tuple/str, does not matter) looking like [1,1]. Amount of values is equal to amount of cuts in b(inner tuples). First 1 is because between (0,),(1,2) there is only one edge from a - (0,1). Second 2 is because there is (1,2) edge only between (0,1) and (2). is it clearer after this explanation or still not so clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a graph, that you want to **partition** in different ways, then count how many edges there is between partitions.

So I wrote a `compute_partitions` function, which given some edges, will give you the different way to partition them according to your rules.
Then calling a method to count the "crossings" between the two partitions.

```py
from typing import List, Tuple


Edge = Tuple[int, int]
Edges = List[Edge]

edges: Edges = [
    (0, 1),
    (0, 2),
    (0, 3),
]

Nodes = List[int]


def compute_partitions(edges: Edges) -> List[Tuple[Nodes, Nodes]]:
    # we want to list all the nodes
    all_unique_nodes = set(node for edge in edges for node in edge)
    # then sort them in ascending order
    sorted_nodes = sorted(all_unique_nodes)
    # and return a sliding partition
    for left_count in range(1, len(sorted_nodes)):  # from 1 to len()-1 inclusive
        left_nodes = sorted_nodes[0:left_count]  # include up to left_count exclusive
        right_nodes = sorted_nodes[left_count:]  # the rest
        yield left_nodes, right_nodes  # could be appended into a list otherwise


def count_edges_between(left_nodes: Nodes, right_nodes: Nodes, edges: Edges) -> int:
    crossings = 0
    for node_a, node_b in edges:
        if node_a in left_nodes:
            if node_b in left_nodes:
                pass
            elif node_b in right_nodes:
                crossings += 1
            else:
                raise ValueError("node not in edges")
        elif node_a in right_nodes:
            if node_b in left_nodes:
                crossings += 1
            elif node_b in right_nodes:
                pass
            else:
                raise ValueError("node not in edges")
        else:
            raise ValueError("node not in edges")
    return crossings

print(list(compute_partitions(edges)))

for nodes_left, nodes_right in compute_partitions(edges):
    print(count_edges_between(nodes_left, nodes_right, edges), nodes_left, nodes_right)
```

```py
[([0], [1, 2, 3]), ([0, 1], [2, 3]), ([0, 1, 2], [3])]
3 [0] [1, 2, 3]
2 [0, 1] [2, 3]
1 [0, 1, 2] [3]
```